# Get value of a property inside jstl tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl, spring-tld

I'm developing a simple tag library in order to centralize the creation of form components.

In my custom tag I need to get the value of the backing object mapped field.

Here is how I pass the field name value to my library:

```
<jsp:directive.attribute name="field" type="java.lang.String" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="The field exposed from the form backing object" />
```

Inside my tag library, using `<form:hidden path="${field}.id" />` from spring tag library works, but how can I get same value not using that library? I do not want to have an input type hidden mapped in my form, but only retrieve the value of that field name.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the spring:eval tag

```
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="object" type="java.lang.Object" required="true" description="The form backing object" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="field" type="java.lang.String" required="true" description="The field name" />

  <spring:eval expression="object[field]" />
```

Comment: It don't works.. theValue variable text value is gas.id, not the real id

Comment: This should works :) +1 Do you think it is possible without specifying object?

Comment: No I don't think its possible whithout specifying the object. Have a look at Spring Roo, it does what you are trying to do : using a tag library to simplify form creation. http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-web.html#jsp-views

Comment: Is from roo that I started to modify tag library :)